Is there a way to determine if the open mailbox is a shared mailbox?
Is there an API to determine if a mailbox in Outlook is a shared mailbox? Also, is it possible to distinguish whether the mailbox is in the user's email compose window or opened in a separate tab?
I used the Office.Mailbox interface, but I couldn't retrieve it.
